# $ax+bx^{5/3} = c$

Tags: roots

in the following equation

$$ax+bx^{5/3} = c$$

$a, b$, and $c$ are constant. Through numerical result I know that $x$ is near zero and positive. I want to find an analytical solution or approximation. I really appreciate if you could help me through this matter.

Comment: Why are you sure one exists? E.g. substituting $u = x^{1/3}$ you get $au^3 + bu^5 = c$, a quintic, which may not generally have any analytic solutions?

Comment: @gt6989b The claim that quintics might not have *analytic solutions* is false. What you are remembering is *expressible in radicals*.

Comment: @flan interesting I just deleted my comment saying much the same as gt. I thought that this was true?

Comment: @flan that's fair. still not sure you can write down a solution to an arbitrary quintic, even in terms of special functions etc.

Comment: @gt6989b It is well known that you can, for all degrees. In the case of the quintic you can write it in terms of the Bring radical, for example.

Comment: @flan +1, thanks for teaching me something new. :) appreciate it a lot

Comment: @gt6989b I have tried your suggestion before. I also tried to form as an exponential form and try Taylor series for $exp(bx^{2-\delta})$ but it becomes too complicated to solve.

Comment: So following @flan's suggestion, perhaps look at the 2 approaches described in Wiki article on [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), transforming your equation to eliminate the cubic term and possibly eventually the quadratic term

Comment: Thanks to @flan 's comments I am trying to find a solution. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* . This is an interesting problem from a numerical point of view. Are $(a,b,c)$ all positive ? How large could be $b$ compared to $a$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your interest. c = 2, and $b = a \times 165.5170826624471$. For example, when a = 60.4246, b = 10001.29897874889, c = 2, I find the approximation of x^* \approx 0.00545.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let us consider some numerical aspects which will (probably) be useful later.

I shall assume that  constants $(a,b,c)$  are all positive.

We are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=a x+bx^{5/3}-c$$ for which
$$f'(x)=a+\frac{5}{3} b x^{ 2/3} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac {10b} {9x^{ 1/3}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f'''(x)=-\frac{10 b}{27 x^{4/3}}$$

Starting at $\color{red}{x_0=0}$, the first iterate of Newton method is $\color{red}{x_1=\frac c a}$ for which
$$f(x_1)=b \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{5/3} >0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x_1)=\frac{10 b}{9 \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{1/3}} >0$$ By Darboux theorem, this means that, even if we start with this probably very poor estimate, Newton method will converge without any overshoot of the solution.

As an example, using $a=60$, $b=10000$ and $c=2$ the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.0333333 \\
 1 & 0.0140051 \\
 2 & 0.0072200 \\
 3 & 0.0055641 \\
 4 & 0.0054253 \\
 5 & 0.0054242
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, there is no risk to generate a better starting point
$$\color{red}{x_2=\frac{c}{a}-\frac{3 b \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{5/3}}{20 \left(2500
   \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{2/3}+9\right)}}$$ at which we can compute the values $f(x_2)$, $f'(x_2)$, $f''(x_2)$, $f'''(x_2)$.

Now, let us use Householder method which will give
$$\color{red}{x_3=x_2+\frac{3 f(x_2) \left(f(x_2) f''(x_2)-2 f'(x_2)^2\right)}{f(x_2)^2 f'''(x_2)+6 f'(x_2)^3-6 f(x_2)   f'(x_2) f''(x_2)}}$$ For the worked example, this should give $x_3=0.0056389$. If we repeat once this last step, this should give $x_4=0.0054242$ which is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As comments say, you can write this as $a u^3 + b u^5 = c$, where $u = x^{1/3}$. This has a real, positive root (if $a, b, c$ are positive, that is). If $u$ is near 1, one (or a few) iterations of Newton's method starting at $u_0 = 1$ should give a precise value. I.e.,

$$u_1 = \frac{2 a + 4 b + c}{3 a + 5 b}$$

(Next one gets hairy...)

Comment: amir said $x$ (and therefore $u$) is near $0$, not $1$. But I agree, if all they want is a solution for a particular set of values for $a,b,c$, then Newton's method is the way to go. No "analytic solution" will give you as good a value with less calculation than Newton's method (excepting when the solution is a low-denominator rational, which is clearly not going to be true here).